# Is $f_n (x)$ is uniformly convergent on $[0, \pi /2]$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Is  $f_n(x) = \cos^n x(1-\cos^nx)$ is uniformly convergent  on $[0, \pi/2]$?

My attempt  : I thinks yes.  here

Sup $\{ |f_n(x) | : x \in  [0, \pi/2]\}= 0$ so $f_n(x) = \cos^n x(1-\cos^nx)$ converge uniformly on $[0,\pi/2]$

Is its true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not converge uniformly. It converges pointwise to the null function, but$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):f_n\left(\arccos\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac12}\right)\right)=\frac14.$$

Comment: sir can u elaboarate more   im not getting  why  u  use $f_n\left(\arccos\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac12}\right)\right)$ ?

Comment: Since $\cos\left(\arccos\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac12}\right)\right)=\sqrt[n]{\frac12}$,$$f_n\left(\arccos\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac12}\right)\right)=\frac12\left(1-\frac12\right)=\frac14.$$